# Trying to load and initialize a shader using jogl

Tags: java, opengl, shader, jogl

Trying to initialize some shaders in `JOGL`.

Any ideas why the error is empty? I check the size of it, and it looks larger than 0 since `"Unknown"` is not printed.

```
vertexShaderProgram = gl.glCreateShader(GL2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShaderProgram = gl.glCreateShader(GL2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.glShaderSource(vertexShaderProgram, 1, vsrc, null, 0);
gl.glCompileShader(vertexShaderProgram);
gl.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderProgram, 1, fsrc, null, 0);
gl.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderProgram);
shaderprogram = gl.glCreateProgram();

gl.glAttachShader(shaderprogram, vertexShaderProgram);
gl.glAttachShader(shaderprogram, fragmentShaderProgram);
gl.glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);
gl.glValidateProgram(shaderprogram);
IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
gl.glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL2.GL_LINK_STATUS, intBuffer);

System.out.println("got link status");

if (intBuffer.get(0) != 1) {
    gl.glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL2.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, intBuffer);
    int size = intBuffer.get(0);
    System.err.println("Program link error: ");
    if (size > 0) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderprogram, size, intBuffer, byteBuffer);
        for (byte b: byteBuffer.array()) {
            System.err.print((char) b);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unknown");
    }
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I get an error on console, but contains no data ..

```
got link status
Program link error:
```

This is my fragment shader ..

```
< FILE :: fragmentShader.txt >
uniform sampler2D fish_y_offset;
uniform float alphavalue;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(fish_y_offset, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor.a=alphavalue;

}
```

and this is my vertex shader ..

```
< FILE :: vertextShader.txt >
uniform float waveTime;
uniform float waveWidth;
uniform float waveHeight;
void main(void)
{
    vec4 v = vec4(gl_Vertex);
    v.y = 11 + sin(waveWidth * v.x + waveTime) * cos(waveWidth * v.z + waveTime) * waveHeight;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * v;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the shader logs after each shader compilation.

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml

Comment: JOGL 2 method: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html#glGetShaderInfoLog(int,%20int,%20java.nio.IntBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer) Example: https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine/blob/master/jme3-jogl/src/main/java/com/jme3/renderer/jogl/JoglRenderer.java#L1076

Comment: thanks @gouessej that jmonkeyengine really helped for the java version of this answer

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I should have used this method here too: https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/blob/master/ardor3d-jogl/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/scene/state/jogl/JoglShaderObjectsStateUtil.java#L533 "Errare humanum est" :s

Comment: @gouessej +1 for the cit :)